# C#: Cursor.Hide() doesn't work on XP

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, cursor, windows-xp

I'm developing a Winforms application in C# using .NET 4.0 CP. Right now it's in beta testing phase and I'm testing the app on various systems running Windows. Win 7 and 8 works great but XP really starts to get on my nerves.

Latest bug that appears, obviously, only on XPs is that cursor doesn't hide using Hide() method. I'm trying to draw my own cursor over PictureBox, as seen in example:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Hide();
}

private void pictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Show();
}

private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //draw some cursor...
}
```

It works the way it should as far as it doesn't run on Win XP.

What might be the problem? .NET 4.0 should work on XP but I keep on encountering new bugs. I've tried to google some advice but haven't come across anything useful yet. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: No simple explanation for this.  Show and Hide are counted, one too many Show call and Hide won't work.  Which could be done by other code that we can't see.  Add some Trace() statements to your code.

Comment: @HansPassant I use Hide and Show in several other places in my code but they never interleave so there is no chance that there will occur two or more Hide (or Show) consecutive calls. When the cursor is hidden, it must be showed before hidden again.

Comment: SO users typically get into trouble and post a question when their assumptions are invalid.  I suspected that you were calling Show/Hide in other places, but of course we can't see them nor have a guess at how they could interact in unexpected ways.  Add the tracing as I recommended, use a counter too.

Comment: Can you try: this.Cursor.Hide(); ?

Comment: @Mobstaa That doesn't work, probably because you can't access static method `Cursor` with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try if

```
this.Refresh();
```

helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunatelly this doesn't help. I've also tried refreshing pictureBox but that's no good either.

Answer (score 0):

Following platforms are supported by the Cursor.Hide() function:

Windows 98, Windows 2000 SP4, Windows CE, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows Mobile for Pocket PC, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Starter Edition

So it will not work on a normal Windows XP machine, only with SP2 installed, the starter edition and the x64 professional edition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where exactly did you find that information? However the problem still remains, I've tested the app on various XP versions with various SPs, but it simply doesn't work anywhere.

Comment: I use 4.0 CP as mentioned above. But the platform requirements are similar, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Why do you have an OnPaint event with: //draw cursor?